# Javascript Array problem ParseInt string inside Array

Tags: arrays, string, numbers, constants, parseint

I have searching during 7 days, in all forum. It's hard, maybe this case is special: (thanks you a lot for help... )

```js
    const ARRAY1 = [



      { Ville:  'Anse-Bertrand (97121)' , taux: 0.6393  },
      { Ville: 'Saint-Louis (97421)', taux: 0.6359  },
      { Ville:  'La Haute-Beaume (05140)', taux:    0.5900  },
      { Ville:  'Fontanès-de-Sault (11140)', taux:  0.5791  },
      { Ville:  'Chambord (41250)', taux:   0.5658  }


    ]


    const ARRAY2 = (ARRAY1.Ville.replace(/\d/g, ""))
    //i want to replace all characteres of all (Ville) by "_". To just have the postal codes.

    var KeySearched = "05140"



    function isTaux (answer) {
      return answer.Ville ==KeySearched ;
    }

    console.log(ARRAY2.find(isTaux).taux);
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what the output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```js
const ARRAY2 = [
  { Ville:  'Anse-Bertrand (97121)' , taux: 0.6393  },
  { Ville: 'Saint-Louis (97421)', taux: 0.6359  },
  { Ville:  'La Haute-Beaume (05140)', taux:    0.5900  },
  { Ville:  'Fontanès-de-Sault (11140)', taux:  0.5791  },
  { Ville:  'Chambord (41250)', taux:   0.5658  }
]


const NewArr = ARRAY2.map(function(a, b) {
    a.Ville = a.Ville.replace(/[\D]/g, "")
    return a
})

console.log(NewArr)
```

Comment: YES ! Thanks you. i didnt know the function a, b? Is how you acces to value 1 array, and value 2 array ??

Comment: Because i saw you put Constname+map (function a//element1?) b //element2? ) and then i understood.

it that way to acces always in Array? interesting... :-)

Comment: @Lasticot glad to help. If I answered your question, please mark it as correct so that it helps anyone else running into the same problem.